# DynamoDB | How to update an item, if the item does not exist yet with PartiQL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, partiql

I would like to make an update call to dynamoDB which:

1. If the ddb item exists, update the existing string set for its new values (adding not replacing),
2. or if the ddb item does not exist yet, create a new item.
3. But both cases should be covered with just one api call.

This is currently possible for me by using the `UpdateItem` operation:

```
val requestParameters =
  s"""
     |{
     |    "TableName": "custom_table_name",
     |    "Key": {
     |          "id": {
     |              "S": "custom_id"
     |          }
     |    },
     |    "UpdateExpression": "ADD user_list :newItem",
     |    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
     |        ":newItem": { "SS": ["user1","user2"] }
     |    }
     |}
     |""".stripMargin
```

But I now would like to switch to **PartiQL** and I came up with the following idea via `ExecuteStatement` operation usage:

```
val requestParameters =
  s"""
     |{
     |    "Statement": "UPDATE custom_table_name SET user_list=SET_ADD(user_list, ?) WHERE id='custom_id'",
     |    "Parameters": [
     |     {
     |       "SS": ['user1','user2']
     |     }
     |    ]
     |}
     |""".stripMargin
```

For the PartiQL solution, if the item does exist, it all works as expected, but if the item does not exist I get:

`"400 Bad Request"/"The conditional request failed"` (as the key doesn't exist yet)

**But I don't want to now having to make a second call to insert a new item under PartiQL, I would rather like both cases to be handled with just 1 API call, as it was possible via UpdateItem usage.**

**Any ideas how this might be possible under PartiQL?**

---

Documentations:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ql-reference.update.html
-> PartiQL has only SET and REMOVE
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions
-> Older UpdateExpressions has SET, REMOVE, **ADD** & DELETE

---

(I'm making the requests directly to the *dynamoDB low level api* without AWS SDK usage)

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called an "upsert".

Here's a twitter thread discussing how it isn't possible in PartiQL: https://twitter.com/__steele/status/1445605614248366088

Comment: Thank you for sharing! I hope they might consider this feature one day.

Comment: How does that thread say that it isn't possible in PartiQL? I'm reading the opposite. However, I can't get it to actually work because of "Statement wasn't well formed, can't be processed: Unexpected token after expression"

Comment: @404usernamenotfound it's kind of hidden in the replies, try this link (and reading the replies before higher up in the thread)  https://twitter.com/pj_naylor/status/1447774200547008513